# How to load data to oracle table from text file and check if record already exists using shell script?

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a comma seperated file with data like this which is from shell script:
id ,  jobname , started,  ended , time
1  ,   A     ,   1130  ,   1200 , 30
2  ,   A      ,  1120   ,  1130 , 10

I need to load these data to a oracle table and need to check before inserting whether the record already exists ,if exists then update else insert .I have used sqlplus for the connection from shell script to oracle .Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If the file is (or can be) on the database server, it sounds like you'd want to create an external table to expose the data and then write a `merge` statement to load the data from the external table into the final table.  If the file is on the client, you could use `SQL*Loader` to load the data into a staging table and then write the same `merge` statement to load the data into the final table.

Comment: Is there any work around without an external table to do it from linux side?

Comment: Why can't you use an external table or `SQL*Loader`?  You could write your own code to parse the file and generate a bunch of individual `merge` statements but that's a lot more work than creating an external table.

Comment: eternal table creation is not approving from management side and use of sqlloader is also not allowed

Comment: Are there specific objections?  Any reason that management is dictating technical solutions?  It's hard to guess at what technical solution management might allow if we don't know why they're objecting to the obvious approaches (and when that isn't in your question).  There's always the option to write your own Java/ Python/ whatever code that parses the file and does the load.  Way more work but maybe management's goal is more programmer busywork.

Comment: it is amazing how management sometimes interferes on the technical side to make things instead of easier ( which is their job ), ten times harder. @JustinCave, love your comment ;)

Comment: I upvote Justin's comment.  I would _love_ to hear why "management" (or, more precisely, "mis-management") forbids the use of external tables and/or sqlldr.

Comment: They doesnt want to create a table just for the sake of loading to an external table.so what I have done is take it from dual and then written the merge statemnet ..and it is working now

Comment: @DhanyaRaj, what a select from dual has anything to do with a file in the filesystem that you can't read from the database unless is an external table ??. Yoiu were saying you need a solution without external tables and without sql loader. I just did that in my answer, even though we all know it is the wrong approach to the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Doing the solution the hardest way**

```
$ cat test.dat
id , jobname , started, ended , time
1 , A , 1130 , 1200 , 30
2 , A , 1120 , 1130 , 10
3 , C , 1120 , 1130 , 10
```

In Oracle

```
SQL>  create table t ( id number, jobname varchar2(1) , started number, ended number, elapsed number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( 1 , 'A' , 1130 , 1200 , 30 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ( 2, 'B' , 1120 , 1130 , 10 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t ;

        ID J    STARTED      ENDED    ELAPSED
---------- - ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 A       1130       1200         30
         2 B       1120       1130         10
```

Under this scenario our program needs to update the record with ID 2 and insert the record with ID 3. This is just a basic shell program to do so, but by far this is the worst way to handle this problem. An external table using the oracle sql loader driver would be much better, easier and faster.

**Code**

```
#/bin/bash 

records=$(cat /home/ftpcpl/test.dat | tail -n +2 | wc -l)
echo "Number of records in file: $records" 

record_exists ()
{

record_id=$1

counter=`sqlplus -S "/ as sysdba" << eof
whenever sqlerror exit 2;
set echo off verify off head off feed off
select count(*) from t where t.id = ${record_id} ;
eof`

if [[ $? -eq 2 ]]; then exit 2; fi 

export counter=$(echo ${counter} | tr -d '\n')

}

UpdateRecord ()
{

${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus "/ as sysdba" << eof >> $logfile
whenever sqlerror exit failure;
update t set jobname = '${jb}' , 
   started =  ${st}  , 
   ended   =  ${en}  , 
   elapsed =  ${ti}  
where id = ${id} ;
commit;
eof

if [[ $? -eq 2 ]]; then exit 2; fi 

}

InsertRecord ()
{

${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus "/ as sysdba" << eof >> $logfile
whenever sqlerror exit failure;
insert into t values ( ${id} , '${jb}' , ${st}  , ${en}  , ${ti} );
commit;
eof

if [[ $? -eq 2 ]]; then exit 2; fi 

}

logfile=test.log 

tail -n +2 /home/ftpcpl/test.dat | 
while read -r line
do
  echo $line    
  export id=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | xargs echo -n )
  export jb=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}' | xargs echo -n )
  export st=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $3}' | xargs echo -n )
  export en=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $4}' | xargs echo -n )
  export ti=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $5}' | xargs echo -n )
 
  record_exists ${id}
  
  if [[ ${counter} -eq 1 ]];
  then
    UpdateRecord 
  else 
    InsertRecord 
  fi 
done
```

**Demo program**

```
./test.sh
Number of records in file: 3
1 , A , 1130 , 1200 , 30
2 , A , 1120 , 1130 , 10
3 , C , 1120 , 1130 , 10
[ftpcpl@scglvdoracd0006 ~]$ cat test.log

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Oct 13 15:46:34 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5
1 row updated.

SQL>
Commit complete.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Oct 13 15:46:36 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5
1 row updated.

SQL>
Commit complete.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Oct 13 15:46:38 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL>
Commit complete.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0
```

**Final records**

```
SQL> select * from t ;

        ID J    STARTED      ENDED    ELAPSED
---------- - ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 A       1130       1200         30
         2 A       1120       1130         10
         3 C       1120       1130         10
```

Comment: you are welcome. I would appreciate if you upvote or accept the answer